# Как в JAVA сконвертнуть строку в дату?

Tags: java

Есть на входе строка типа "2012-04-04" (приходит из MySQL). как ее сконвертить в тип Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try{
    String str_date="2012-04-04";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);
    System.out.println("Today is " +date );
}
catch (Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private static final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd";
private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN);

private Date parseDate(final String stringDate) throws ParseException {
    return FORMAT.parse(stringDate);
}
```

Comment: Имейте в виду, SimpleDateFormat не thread safe.